# Entity Framework Reusable Filters with Generics and Interfaces

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I am trying to write reusable filtering queries for reporting purposes. Current criteria is that

1. User should be able to filter based on date
2. User can filter reports by user information

For this, I have something like this:

```
public class ReportQueryProvider<TCriteria, TModel> : IReportQueryProvider<TCriteria, TModel>
    where TModel : class, IReportable<TModel>
    where TCriteria : ReportCriteria
{
    public Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> Filter(TCriteria criteria)
    {
        var a = PredicateBuilder.New<TModel>();
        if (criteria.StartDateObject!=null)
            a = a.And(x => x.date >= criteria.StartDateObject);

        if (criteria.EndDateObject != null)
            a = a.And(x => x.date <= criteria.EndDateObject);

        var userFilter = QueryExtensions.UserCommonFilter(criteria);
        a = a.And(m => userFilter.Invoke(m.FilterUser));
        return a;
    }
}
```

It is working fine for `date` filter because each Model/Table has `date` field/property but User Association for each table can be different. That's why I created interface with property `FilterUser` and each table has to implement it and return/map its actual User property in it.

Now, since `FilterUser` is computed property, entity framework won't be able to work with this.

To get around this, I tried both `DelegateDecompiler` and `Microsoft.Linq.Translations` but both of these doesn't seem to work when I try to use them via above **Filter** method which uses Generics and interfaces. In case of `DelegateDecompiler` I get error that object reference is not set. In case of Linq.Translations, it behaves as if translation was never used or it isn't present.

However, if I try to use them outside of Generics (in non Generics) way, they work as expected and I am able to use `FilterUser` property with EF. They even work if I change generic where condition from `IReportable<TModel>` to one of the concrete Model class implementing this interface.

My sample model class:

```
public partial class Dis_UserTransactions : IReportable<Dis_UserTransactions>
{
    private static readonly CompiledExpression<Dis_UserTransactions, User> filterUserExpression
        = DefaultTranslationOf<Dis_UserTransactions>.Property(e => e.FilterUser).Is(e => e.User1);

    static Dis_UserTransactions()
    {
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public User FilterUser => filterUserExpression.Evaluate(this);
}
```

Is it possible to make it work?

P.S. I am already using LinqKit.

Comment: have you seen [this](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/05/29/missing-ef-feature-workarounds-filters/)

Comment: What kind of error is EF giving you?

Comment: The specified type member 'FilterUser' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.